# Does JMeter catch/intercept/"wait for" request?

Tags: jmeter

I need to test a scenario where a request to a custom microservice "A" causes microservice "A" to provide a callback to the endpoint "B".

The question is, is there a component in JMeter that can wait for/catch the request?
Bzw. How can I realize that scenario with JMeter?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't know anything about endpoint "B".

If you can query endpoint "B" for the status, like whether the callback has been received or not you can put this call under the [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and periodically run it. Then the whole sequence can be added to the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller), this way you will get end-to-end processing time.

In case of [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) you can add a library supporting them to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), this way JMeter can "wait" for updates from the server. See [How to Load Test SSE Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-sse) article for more details.

Comment: hey Dimitri, many thanks for the reply. I have managed to reproduce the example described in "How to load ...", but in this case the coacher propers to initiate the communication to third-party-server (wiki) for triggering the response inside of JavaSamplerClient. In my case, my "JavaSamplerClient" might wait for the incoming connection like REST/WebService/SOAP. To implement that idea, I would use the Springboot framework because it can easily provide me with a REST/WebService/SOAP endpoint, but I am afraid it is not supported for the JavaSamplerClient or I don't know about it.

Comment: Dimitri, do you know, is it possible to develop a SpringBoot application, which might be used inside the JMeter as the JavaSamplerClient implementation?

Thanks in advance.